# How to pass (cli) arguments by file in Ant

Tags: php, ant, exec, phpcodesniffer

I'm using Ant to build my project, generate docs and check coding strandard violations. I use some external tool through exec task. Exec prefixes the output lines with `[exec]`
This string messes my output up.
If I specify the `-e` switch in the command line, it remains quiet.

Is there a way to

- specify the `-e` switch on every run in the build.xml file?
- or something else equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Java System Properties will help ... see http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#sysprops

In particular, I think that setting the property `build.compiler.emacs` to `true` may help. Anyway, I doubt that setting (or, re-setting it via ant-extensions) it in the build file helps, as properties are designed to be immutable.